# Hard-Coding date string much faster than DateTime in SELECT?

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, indexing

I have a very large table (15 million rows, this is an audit table).

I need to run a query that checks for occurrences in the audit table that are after a certain date and meet certain criteria (I am looking for audit records that took place on current day only)

When I run:

```
SELECT Field1, Field2 FROM AUDIT_TABLE WHERE AUDIT_DATE >= '8/9/12'
```

The results come back fairly quick (a few seconds, not bad for 15M rows)

When I run:

```
SELECT Field1, Field2 FROM AUDIT_TABLE WHERE AUDIT_DATE >= @DateTime
```

It takes 11-15 seconds and does a full table scan.

The actual field I am querying against is a DATETIME type, and the index is also on that field.

Comment: Is `AUDIT_TABLE` indexed or partitioned on `AUDIT_DATE`? It's possible that your second example prevents the index from being used.

Comment: Compare execution plans; your parameterised version will most probably have an execution plan that works best for all possible inputs, but maybe not the best plan for a specific parameter value...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sounds like you are stuck with a bad plan, probably because someone used a parameter at some point that selected enough of the table that a table scan was the most efficient way for that parameter value. Try running the query once this way:

```
SELECT ... FROM AUDIT_TABLE WHERE AUDIT_DATE >= @DateTIme OPTION (RECOMPILE);
```

And then change your code this way:

```
SELECT ... FROM dbo.AUDIT_TABLE WHERE AUDIT_DATE >= @DateTime;
```

Using the `dbo.` prefix will at the very least prevent different users with different schemas from polluting the plan cache with different versions of the plan. It will also disassociate future queries from the bad plan that is stored.

If you are going to vary between selecting recent rows (small %) and a lot of rows, I would probably just leave the OPTION (RECOMPILE) on there. Paying the minor CPU penalty in recompilation every time is going to be cheaper than getting stuck with a bad plan for most of your queries.

Another trick I've seen used to bypass parameter sniffing:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.whatever
  @DateTime DATETIME
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  DECLARE @dt DATETIME;
  SET @dt = @DateTime;

  SELECT ... WHERE AUDIT_DATE >= @dt;
END
GO
```

It's kind of a dirty and unintuitive trick, but it gives the optimizer a better glimpse at the parameter value and a better chance to optimize for that value.

Comment: This was excellent, thank you. I was using the dbo prefix already (just left that out for fewer characters in the code sample), but it's good advice for any readers anyway. It appears that there must be a bad execution plan, as you said. Adding the OPTION (RECOMPILE) did the trick and it runs now in 1 second. I had tried WITH RECOMPILE at the procedure level initially with the same train of thought but that did not seem to work, where as your WHERE-clause level recompile did. Thanks again!