# DB2 Inner Query slow but fast with hardcoded values

Tags: sql, performance, db2

I'm getting a weird behavior in DB2 sql. (DB2 9.7)
Follow is a sample query to fetch employee salary, status and band..

```
SELECT
                EMP.STATUS,
                COUNT(*)               AS EMP_COUNT,
                GRP.GROUP_NAME
FROM
                EMPLOYEE EMP,
                EMPLOYEE_SALARY ES,
                GROUP_TABLE GRP
WHERE
                EMP.SALARY > 
                             (select max(EMP1.SALARY) from  
                             EMPLOYEE EMP1, FINANCIAL_YEAR FY where 
                              date(EMP1.JOIN_DT) = '2013-01-01' 
                              and date(EMP1.DATE_TS) = date(FY.CURRENT_DT) - 2 days)
                AND EMP.SALARY = E.EMPID
                AND E.SALARY_GRP = GRP.BAND_GROUP
                AND GRP.RANGE_SALARY = 'BAND-10'
                GROUP BY
                        EMP.STATUS,
                        GRP.GROUP_NAME
```

The EMP (employee) table contains around 1million rows. Rest of the tables are very small. 
The query takes around 10secs to execute

But when I hard-code the inner query

From

```
select max(EMP1.SALARY) from  EMPLOYEE EMP1, FINANCIAL_YEAR FY where 
        date(EMP1.JOIN_DT) = '2013-01-01' 
        and date(EMP1.DATE_TS) = date(FY.CURRENT_DT) - 2 days
```

to

```
select max(EMP1.SALARY) from  EMPLOYEE EMP1, FINANCIAL_YEAR FY where 
       date(EMP1.JOIN_DT) = '2013-01-01' 
       and date(EMP1.DATE_TS) = '2013-06-01'
```

The result comes within a second !!

"FINANCIAL_YEAR FY" table is a very small table with around 50 rows and hence I don't know why the inner query takes time of itself when its dynamic but very fast when I hard-code

Some additional Info

- EMPID is integer
- DATE_TS is timestamp
- CURRENT_DT, JOIN_DT is date
- Rest all are VARCHAR
- EMPID is indexed

Comment: What are the data types for `EMP1.JOIN_DT`, `EMP1.DATE_TS` and `FY.CURRENT_DT`?  And what are example values?  *(The cause of your problem is calling the function `DATE` on the fields you are joining on, doing so **destroys** the ability to use indexes.)*

Comment: @Dems I had thought too initially. But when I hardcode is it exactly the same? FY.CURRENT_DT if queried alone will come in milliseconds.

Comment: Hqve you seen the access plan? what does it say?

Comment: Paste the execution plan into your question. I think that inner SELECT statement will have to execute once per row. That's a sure performance killer.

Comment: The DB2 optimizer _may_ be able to 'cheat' when you do the hardcoding, by substituting a range query (now, look, I don't know if it **actually** can).

Comment: Simple predicates like date(EMP1.DATE_TS) = date(FY.CURRENT_DT) can be used by the storage engine to filter out rows as they are read from disk. However this only works for direct comparisons and some of the very simple built in functions. As soon as you throw the calculation in there all the rows get fed into the buffer pool and the filtering is done later.

Comment: hi guys, it almost seems to be related to DB2 internal optimiser. I have found in http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/transactsql/thread/abd9da60-fb70-4ece-a101-2610e8293f93 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11885912/hard-coding-date-string-much-faster-than-datetime-in-select that recompiling the value beforehand speeds up considerably.

Answer (score 0):

You might try this version (I'm assuming the `E` references are supposed to be the `ES` alias, otherwise the statement shouldn't run).  Among other things, you should ditch the 'implicit join' (comma-separated `FROM` clause), especially if you ever start dealing with `LEFT JOIN`s.

```
WITH Maximum_Salary (max) as (SELECT MAX(EMP.SALARY) 
                              FROM EMPLOYEE EMP
                              JOIN FINANCIAL_YEAR FY
                                ON (FY.CURRENT_DT - 2 DAYS) >= EMP.DATE_TS
                                   AND (FY.CURRENT_DT - 1 DAYS) < EMP.DATE_TS
                              WHERE EMP.JOIN_DT = DATE('2013-01-01')

SELECT EMP.STATUS, COUNT(*) AS EMP_COUNT, GRP.GROUP_NAME
FROM EMPLOYEE EMP
JOIN GROUP_TABLE GRP
  ON GRP.RANGE_SALARY = 'BAND-10'
JOIN EMPLOYEE_SALARY ES
  ON ES.EMPID = EMP.SALARY
     AND ES.SALARY_GRP = GRP.BAND_GROUP
JOIN Maximum_Salary 
  ON Maximum_Salary <= EMP.SALARY
GROUP BY EMP.STATUS, GRP.GROUP_NAME
```

If you aren't used to them already, the `WITH` syntax is a Common Table Expression (or CTE) - effectively, it's an inline view.  These *can* result in temp-tables being created, in some instances, but otherwise can save you a lot of typing (they're also how recursive queries are performed).  I've managed to get the references to `EMP.DATE_TS` into a form that can use an index (no help for the date-math on `FY.CURRENT_DT`, although as a small table that shouldn't matter much).

Note that you may still need to perform additional tuning, especially depending on what indices you may (not) have.